# object element not growing auto

Tags: html

i have 2 problem with object element in html,

i use this object

```
<object id='obj1' data='Manager/First_Manager.aspx' type='text/html' width='100%' height='1000' style='background:#FBFBFB;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;'></object>
```

problem 1: i force determinate height for object, what do i do for growing object element auto?

problem2: when i move between two big pages, at the return to first page scroll not return to top of page. it stay in the place of the before page.

Answer (score 0):

for problem1: `height:auto` will helps....(Need some more code structure to dig the issue)

for your problem two put this javascript in your page for take the page to top.

(Note: Below code using jQuery you must refer jQuery.js in your page. )

```
<scripttype="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This is Jquery, not vanilla js. Please mention that in your answer as someone naive will get errors